# How to removing registry key values at the time of uninstall the msi installer in wix?

Tags: wix, 64-bit, windows-installer

I am trying to develop a simple msi installer with wix.It is succeeded(install/uninstall) for 32 bit machine. When i develop the installer for 64 bit machine it is installing successfully but at the time of uninstall registry key are not removing and files are not removing from system32 and systemwow64 folders.

The wix configuration i am using is below :

```
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
          <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder" Name='PFiles'/>
          <Directory Id="SystemFolder" Name="sys32"></Directory>
          <Directory Id="System64Folder" Name="sys64"></Directory>
        </Directory>

    <DirectoryRef Id='SystemFolder'>
          <Component Id  = "Sys32Comp"
                     UninstallWhenSuperseded ="yes"
                Guid = "7E079CEA-4A90-4C27-99F1-74FD4201BF5B">
            <File
                 Id      = 'sample'
                 Name    = 'samp.dll'
                 DiskId  = '1'
                 Source  = '$(sys.CURRENTDIR)\32\samp.dll'
                 KeyPath = 'yes'/>
    <RegistryKey Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall"
           Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\SCardMiniDrv"
           Root="HKLM">
              <RegistryValue Name="ATR" Type="binary" Value="3b7a9500008065a20131013d72d641" />
              <RegistryValue Name="ATRMask" Type="binary" Value="ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff" />
            </RegistryKey>
          </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>

<DirectoryRef Id='System64Folder'>
          <Component Id  = "Sys64Comp"
                     Win64="yes"
                     UninstallWhenSuperseded ="yes"
                     Guid = "A6CA464D-5A20-47E0-9C22-2A49DD53DC1D">
        <File
             Id      = 'sample2'
             Name    = 'samp_64.dll'
             DiskId  = '1'
             Source  = '$(sys.CURRENTDIR)\64\samp64.dll'
             KeyPath = 'yes'/>
<RegistryKey Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall"
                   Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\SmartCards\SCardMiniDrv"
                   Root="HKLM"
                      ForceDeleteOnUninstall="yes">
              <RegistryValue Name="ATR" Type="binary" Value="3b7a9500008065a20131013d72d641" />
              <RegistryValue Name="ATRMask" Type="binary" Value="ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff" />
         </RegistryKey>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```